# how to increase apex 5.0.3 report font size

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive report retrieving numbers and I want to make these numbers a little bigger.

How can I do that? Is that even a thing in apex?

How can I increase the report overall font size or a specific column font size?

I tried changing the region item size to Large and XLarge but that changed nothing.

I keep finding posts suggesting something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA td{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

but I don't know where to put it to apply it to the report/region or column I want to apply that font to.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilies to do this. You need to open column properties and find there a `Column formatting` section. There are following fields:

- `HTML Expression`. Here you can put an HTML code, which will be inserted in a table cell. For example:

  ```
  <div style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">#COLUMN_NAME#</div>
  ```

  `#COLUMN_NAME#` here is a substitution string, it will be replaced with the value of sql column with name `COLUMN_NAME`. Put the name of your column here. You can even make column formatting dependent on value of another column.
- `CSS Classes`. A name of a CSS class, which is be described in a css file or in page's properties (for example, `CSS` -> `Inline`). This class will be applied to the table cell.
- `CSS Style`. Inline css style, will be added directly to the sell. For example, put there

  ```
  font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;
  ```

You can use one of these ways or combine them.

Comment: Under column formatting I only get HTML Expression, and when i use your suggestion nothing happens, the font is the same

Comment: You have only "HTML Expression" because it is an Interactive Report. Anyway, this should work - I've just checked this on IR in APEX 5.0. You need to use debug tools in a browser to check, why this style isn't applied. It could be an another style, result of work of a javascript code, a typo in HTML, etc.

Comment: i found that it's being overridden by another styling coming from a div, do you know how to find that div and make it not override my formatting?

Comment: Actually, I'm not as good in HTML/CSS as in APEX. Usually, `div` block inherits settings from outer blocks, but if you add a new inline style like here, inherited values should be overridden. You can try to add `!important` after each setting: `font-size: 18px !important; font-weight: bold !important;`, but it is a quite dirty trick. Or ask a new question about HTML/CSS formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking aloud: if this particular IR has "small font" and you want to enlarge it, I presume that all other pages in your application use the same, small font. Is that so? If YES, an out-of-a-box solution: why wouldn't you simply enlarge the whole page in your browser? In Mozilla Firefox, shortcut keys for that are [**Ctrl +**] (press Ctrl, hold it and press "plus" sign). Because, maybe you made it smaller by accident and didn't notice it.

Comment: no it's this page only actually :) the rest i can enlarge just fine, this one something is overriding my setting for it